# Best way to prevent a node_modules package from updating

Tags: javascript, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I have downloaded/installed a node_module (npm package)...
I have played around with the internal files to suit my needs inside the node_modules folder.
It is the most convenient for me to just use it as a node_module, but I'm worried that the next time I update npm packages it might update and erase all of the changes I have made.
What is the best way to make sure only that particular package should not be updated?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the version of that package specific in package.json file.
For example you manually added **3.0.0 version of express** in dependencies or devDependencies, change the entry of express as:

> **"express":"3.0.0"**

Answer (score 3):

You can store your own/modified packages either locally (e.g. in a common place outside of the project) or in the cloud (e.g. GitHub) and then reference the package via the file path or repository URL respectively.

Check here:

- [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)
- [Git URLs as Dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies)

Comment: What if I just delete that package name in package.json ?  does that work too?  That means I can still access it in node_modules but it will never update and never be overwritten, correct???

Comment: @preston If you manually remove the name of your custom package from `package.json`, then your `package-lock.json` will  be out of sync with the `package.json`, thus you'll have to run `npm install` or `yarn` again, and your custom package will disappear from the `node_modules` folder. But in the original source folder, your package will of course still exist.

Comment: For some reason package-lock.json is not showing up in my project.  So I've deleted the name of the custom package in package.json but the custom package is still inside my node_modules....normally I do not include all of the node_modules in my git repository but this time I plan to just allow the custom package inside the node_modules folder to be included when I git upload... what do u think of this?  this works right?

Comment: `package-lock.json` was introduced in [npm version 5.x.x](https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8). By default `package-lock.json` is created automatically, unless you explicitly [disable it](https://codeburst.io/disabling-package-lock-json-6be662f5b97d). And the package should indeed disappear from `node_modules` once you manually remove it from `package.json`. Looks like it depends on the npm version. Which npm version do you have?

Comment: I would store and version these custom packages in a separate repository and only the custom ones (!). For each package you can simply create an independent repository or simply put all of them in a single repo and save each of them as separate completely independent branch. And refer to them via the respective [repo link (and branchname)](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies), e.g. git://github.com/npm/my-custom-packges.git#jquery-v42

Comment: good idea....i lost all my modifications a few hours ago after installing a different package and doing yarn start......had to redo everything...now I've done the yarn add ./nameOfCustomPackage....making sure nameOfCustomPackage folder and files are there of course..... to avoid losing all my modifications again....